# How can I set my own MongoId with Doctrine ODM for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, php-mongodb, doctrine-odm

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/**
 * @ODM\Document()
 */
class My_Doctrine_Model
{
    /** @ODM\id */
    protected $id;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($value)
    {
        $this->id = $value;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And the code

```
$myModel = new My_Doctrine_Model();
$myModel->setId(new MongoId());

// Id is my set id

$dm->persist($myModel);

// Id is my set id

$dm->flush();

// Id is overwritten and the object is inserted with an other one
```

Why does Doctrine override my set id? And is there a way I can prevent this?

The new Id is set in `PersistenceBuilder::prepareInsertData` when the check to see if an id is set says it isn't. I don't know why the id field is left out of the change set.

#### Update

I read a little more code and found that the reason is the last `if` in `UnitOfWork::getDocumentActualData`.

```
else if ( ! $class->isIdentifier($name) || $class->isIdGeneratorNone()) {
    $actualData[$name] = $value;
}
```

There is no `else` so no value get set for the id.
Is this a deliberate design choice by the developers?

## Solved

This was updated in a recent commit which I haven't updated to. I am not completely sure this is intended though.
https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/commit/fb2447c01cb8968255383ac5700f95b4327468a3#L2L503

Answer (score 3):

You could use a custom ID strategy using Doctrine ODM's annotations eg -

```
/** Document */
class MyPersistentClass
{
    /** @Id(strategy="NONE") */
    private $id;

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    //...
}
```

More information regarding the different custom ID strategies availavle for Doctrine ODM can be found here - http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#basic-mapping-identifiers